# Enable ValidationRule if checkbox is checked

Tags: wpf, vb.net, validation

I want to validate some controls, but only if my checkbox is checked. (in this example i only show one textbox to validate)

I tried to work with BindingGroup, but this means that the checkbox is validated too which gives me wrong results.

Now I try it with MultiBinding:

```
<CheckBox Name="chkUseLqv"
              Grid.Row="6"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Margin="0,0,8,0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Content="Use LQV"
              IsChecked="{Binding LqvConfigurationEnabled}" />

[...]

<GroupBox Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.RowSpan="6"
          Grid.Column="4"
          Margin="5"
          Header="LQV Configuration"
          IsEnabled="{Binding LqvConfigurationEnabled}">
  <Grid>
    <TextBox Name="txtLqvDatabaseServer"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="1"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}">
      <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{Converters:LqvConfigurationMultiBindingConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
          <MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
            <LocalValidationRules:LqvDatabaseServerValidator />
          </MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
          <Binding ElementName="chkUseLqv" Path="IsChecked" />
          <Binding Path="LqvDatabaseServer" />
        </MultiBinding>
      </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
  </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

My Validator:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Namespace ValidationRules
  Public Class LqvDatabaseServerValidator
    Inherits ValidationRule

    Public Overrides Function Validate(ByVal value As Object, ByVal cultureInfo As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As System.Windows.Controls.ValidationResult
      Dim useLqv = CType(value, Object()).OfType(Of Boolean).First()
      Dim valueFromSource = CType(value, Object()).OfType(Of String).FirstOrDefault()

      If useLqv Then
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueFromSource) Then
          Return New ValidationResult(False, "This field is required!")
        End If

        If Not (
          Regex.IsMatch(valueFromSource, "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$") OrElse
          Regex.IsMatch(valueFromSource, "^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$")
          ) Then
          Return New ValidationResult(False, "Invalid input!")
        End If
      End If

      Return ValidationResult.ValidResult
    End Function
  End Class
End Namespace
```

The converter:

```
Imports System.Windows.Markup

Namespace Converters
  Public Class LqvConfigurationMultiBindingConverter
    Inherits MarkupExtension
    Implements IMultiValueConverter

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Private _orig As Object()

    Public Function Convert(ByVal values() As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert
      _orig = values
      Return values.OfType(Of String).FirstOrDefault()
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetTypes() As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object() Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
      Return _orig
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ProvideValue(ByVal serviceProvider As System.IServiceProvider) As Object
      Return New LqvConfigurationMultiBindingConverter()
    End Function
  End Class
End Namespace
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

Define a style in resources:

```
<Style x:Key="lqvDependingFields" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate />
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chkUseLqv, Path=IsChecked}" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}" />
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Have a checkbox:

```
<CheckBox Name="chkUseLqv"
          Grid.Row="6"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Margin="0,0,8,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Content="Use LQV"
          IsChecked="{Binding LqvConfigurationEnabled}" />
```

Use the style on your control:

```
    <TextBox Name="txtLqvDatabaseServer"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="1"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             DependencyProperties:AttachedWindowProperties.HasValidationError="{Binding LqvDatabaseServerValidationError}"
             Style="{StaticResource lqvDependingFields}">
      <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True"
                 Path="LqvDatabaseServer"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
          <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <LocalValidationRules:LqvDatabaseServerValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
          </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
      </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Dependency Property:

```
#Region "HasValidationErrorProperty"

    Public Shared ReadOnly HasValidationErrorProperty As DependencyProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HasValidationError", GetType(Boolean), GetType(AttachedWindowProperties),
                                          New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(False, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                                                        Nothing, AddressOf CoerceHasValidationError))

    Public Shared Function GetHasValidationError(ByVal d As DependencyObject) As Boolean
      Return CBool(d.GetValue(HasValidationErrorProperty))
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub SetHasValidationError(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal value As Boolean)
      d.SetValue(HasValidationErrorProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function CoerceHasValidationError(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal baseValue As Object) As Object
      Dim result As Boolean = CBool(baseValue)

      If BindingOperations.IsDataBound(d, HasValidationErrorProperty) Then
        If GetHasErrorDescriptor(d) Is Nothing Then
          Dim desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Validation.HasErrorProperty, d.GetType)
          desc.AddValueChanged(d, AddressOf OnHasErrorChanged)
          SetHasErrorDescriptor(d, desc)
          result = Validation.GetHasError(d)
        End If
      Else
        If GetHasErrorDescriptor(d) IsNot Nothing Then
          Dim desc As DependencyPropertyDescriptor = GetHasErrorDescriptor(d)
          desc.RemoveValueChanged(d, AddressOf OnHasErrorChanged)
          SetHasErrorDescriptor(d, Nothing)
        End If
      End If

      Return result
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub OnHasErrorChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
      Dim d As DependencyObject = TryCast(sender, DependencyObject)

      If d IsNot Nothing Then
        d.SetValue(HasValidationErrorProperty, d.GetValue(Validation.HasErrorProperty))
      End If
    End Sub

    Private Shared ReadOnly HasErrorDescriptorProperty As DependencyProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HasErrorDescriptor", GetType(DependencyPropertyDescriptor), GetType(AttachedWindowProperties))

    Private Shared Function GetHasErrorDescriptor(ByVal d As DependencyObject) As DependencyPropertyDescriptor
      Return CType(d.GetValue(HasErrorDescriptorProperty), DependencyPropertyDescriptor)
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub SetHasErrorDescriptor(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal value As DependencyPropertyDescriptor)
      d.SetValue(HasErrorDescriptorProperty, value)
    End Sub

#End Region
```

Where `LqvDatabaseServer` and `LqvDatabaseServerValidationErrors` are properties in my ViewModel.